# How to move a div to another animatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have the code below and i would like to know how move a div to another animatedly? My idea is create a life ruler where each year will be a place on ruler.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-BR'>
<head>
    <title>Ruler</title>
    <style>
        .rule{
            height: 40px;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .unit {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0; 
            border-left: 2px solid black;
            border-right: 2px solid black;
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
            height: 15px;
            width: 16px;
            padding-top: calc(100%-15px);
            float: left;
        }

        .box {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 30px;
            width: 10px;
            left: 1px;
            top: -20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="rule">
        <div id="d1" style="left: 0px" class="unit"><div class="box"></div></div>
        <div id="d2" style="left: 18px" class="unit"></div>
        <div id="d3" style="left: 36px" class="unit"></div>
        <div id="d4" style="left: 54px" class="unit"></div>
        <div id="d5" style="left: 72px" class="unit"></div>
    </div>



    <input type="button" id="back" value="<<"/>
    <input type="button" id="forward" value=">>"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#forward").click(function(){
                    $(".box").parent().next().html($(".box"));
            });
            $("#back").click(function(){
                    $(".box").parent().prev().html($(".box"));
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I tried this:

```
if(Math.abs(parseFloat($(".box").css("margin-left"))) < (11 + 18 * 3)){ 
  $(".box").animate({"marginLeft":"+=18px"});
}
```

but, I can not know which div it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the div with class 'box' outside your divs.

```
<div class="rule">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div id="d1" style="left: 0px" class="unit"></div>
    <div id="d2" style="left: 18px" class="unit"></div>
    <div id="d3" style="left: 36px" class="unit"></div>
    <div id="d4" style="left: 54px" class="unit"></div>
    <div id="d5" style="left: 72px" class="unit"></div>
</div>
```

Then apply these styles

```
.rule{
        height: 40px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .unit {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        height: 15px;
        width: 16px;
        padding-top: calc(100%-15px);
        float: left;
    }

    .box {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: yellow;
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 30px;
        width: 10px;
        left: 3px;
        bottom: -0px;
    }
```

Then your javascript will work:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var $box = $(this);

    $box.animate({"marginLeft":"+=18px"});
});
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3K5mw/

And this final fiddle to find your div reference: http://jsfiddle.net/3K5mw/2/

Comment: I tried this how I told in the end of question, I need to know in which div the box are.

Comment: Better add `z-index:1` to `.box` to make its half lower part clickable too. http://jsfiddle.net/3K5mw/1/

Comment: Thank you Oriol for the modified CSS.

Luciano see modified fiddle in answer.